# Unix Syntax Issue on Adding lines, leading spaces, and a string with SED script

Tags: unix, sed

Unix noob here.  I'm working on a unix script that does a simple find/replace.  The script is meant to find a line ending in "_development", then add a new line that contains the string "  password: test".

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -e 's/$"_development"/ a\  password: test/'  original_file > new_file
```

I don't get any errors when I run this, but it doesn't actually do what I need. It adds the new line, but doesn't add the string.  I think this syntax should work.  Does it matter that I'm cranking this out on a Mac.  Most importantly, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your search pattern is `$"_development"`, which looks for an empty string at the end of a line followed by a literal `"_development"`.  It's impossible to have anything after the end of a line -- you really should write `"_development"$` instead.  The `$` always goes at the end.

Something like this should work, assuming you're using a version of sed (such as GNU sed) which can insert newlines:

```
sed -e 's/"_development"$/\0\n  password: test/' original_file > new_file
```

The `\0` says to use the entire matched pattern (so that we don't delete the `"_development"` part), and the `\n` inserts a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the helping with my mispaced "$".  For some reason, though, I can't seem to manage to get the string in the new line added.  The new line appears, but there's nothing in it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sed -e 's/.*_development.$/password: test/' original_file > new_file
```

Assuming you want to replace the line with "_development at the end". If you wanted to append the new new line after the matched one then use

```
sed -e 's/.*_development.$/\0\npassword: test/' test.txt > new_file.txt
```

This adds the `\0\n` to replace with the matched line and append the new one, as suggested by Adam.

However, not having a mac myself, I can't say for sure that these will work for you. Here is an article that may provide a little more info about newlines with sed on mac: http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac, very likely you need a literal newline in your sed command:

```
sed -e '/_development$/a\
   password: test/'
```